# Relational database from XML

Tags: xml, database

I am trying to learn to create a relational database schema from a given XML format. the format is as follows

```
 <product description:"Cardigan Sweater">
 <catalog-item gender:"Men's ">
  <item-number>QWZ5 67 1 </item-number>
  <price>39.95</price>
  <size description:"Medium">
   <color>Red</color>
   <color>BurgundY</color>
   </size>
   <size description:" Large ">
    <color>Red</color>
    <color>BurgundY</color>
   <lsize>
 </catalog-item>
 <catalog_item gender"'Women's">
  <item-number>RRX9 8 5 6</item-number>
  <price>42.5O</Price>
  <size description:"Medium">
   <color>Red</color>
   <color>Navy</color>
   <color>Burgundy</color>
   <color>Black</color>
  </size>
  <size description:" Extra Large ">
   <color>Burgundy</color>
   <color>Black</color>
  </size>
 </catalog_item>
</product>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be translated into following tables, but in the real world I'll define much simpler structure (do you have schema for this XML?).

```
table Product {id_product, description}
table CatalogItem {id_catalogitem, id_product, gender, number, price}
table CatalogItemSize {id_catalogitemsize, id_catalogitem, description}
table CatalogItemSizeColor {id_catalogitemsizecolor, id_catalogitemsize, id_color}
table Color {id_color, description}
```

Comment: That DB should cover just this XML or there are some other info it should be stored along?

Comment: Just this.. The xml I have given above is the only thing given

Comment: Example you provided doesn't cover all the details. Thats the reason I asked for a schema. But in general - every table should contain all attributes for an element and child elements which can occured just once. Any repeatable element have to be placed in another table which should reference parent table.

Comment: Thank you very much... can you please tell me why the table catalog and catalog item have similar attributes?

Comment: That was an error. I've updated my answer - table Catalog is deleted to be conform to XML.